# open and save xlsx as csv file with vscript

Tags: vbscript

I have this script that work fine with xls, but I wanted to use it for xlsx.  I changed the extension to .xlsx and modified the obj.workbook link to ,51.  It doesnt perform the open operation but I'm not sure what i'm missing.

```
WorkingDir = "C:\Test\Excel"
savedir="C:\Test\"      
Extension = ".xlsx"

Dim fso, myFolder, fileColl, aFile, FileName, SaveName
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(WorkingDir)
Set fileColl = myFolder.Files

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each aFile In fileColl
ext = Right(aFile.Name,4)
name= Left(aFile.Name,Len(aFile.Name)-3)         REM changed 
If UCase(ext) = UCase(extension) Then
'open excel
FileName = Left(aFile,InStrRev(aFile,"."))
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(aFile)
SaveName = savedir & name & "csv"            REM changed 
objWorkbook.SaveAs SaveName,51
objWorkbook.Close 
End If
Next
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set fileColl = Nothing
fso.DeleteFile(WorkingDir&"\*"&Extension) REM changed
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wezel: Have the following lines as generic and the same is causing you the issue when there is change of extension as the length varies

**Old Code**

```
ext = Right(aFile.Name,4)
name= Left(aFile.Name,Len(aFile.Name)-3)
```

**Revised Code**

```
ext = Right(aFile.Name,Len(Extension))
name= Left(aFile.Name,Len(aFile.Name)-Len(Extension))
```

Have the code as generic as the one below, so it will work for all the situations and only you need to vary the first four lines according to your need

**Modified Code**

```
WorkingDir = "C:\Test\Excel"
savedir="C:\Test\"      
Extension = ".xlsx"
neededextension= ".csv"
Dim fso, myFolder, fileColl, aFile, FileName, SaveName
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(WorkingDir)
Set fileColl = myFolder.Files

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each aFile In fileColl
ext = Right(aFile.Name,Len(Extension))      REM changed
name= Left(aFile.Name,Len(aFile.Name)-Len(Extension))         REM changed

If UCase(ext) = UCase(extension) Then
'open excel
FileName = Left(aFile,InStrRev(aFile,"."))
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(aFile)
SaveName = savedir & name & neededextension            REM changed 
objWorkbook.SaveAs SaveName,51
objWorkbook.Close 
End If
Next
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set fileColl = Nothing
fso.DeleteFile(WorkingDir&"\*"&Extension) REM changed
Set fso = Nothing
```

Kindly let me know if this fit as generic one as you needed

Comment: Thanks again!  I just repurposed it to handle the 4 character extension rather than 3.  This is much cleaner and I will for sure be using this.  Also, 51 isnt the convert code for a csv file.  It is 23 if anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You pay the price for 'rolling your own' file spec parsing:

```
>> Extension = ".xlsx"
>> WScript.Echo Len(Extension)
>> ext = Right("a.xlsx", 4)
>> WScript.Echo Len(ext)
>> WScript.Echo CStr(UCase(ext) = UCase(extension))
>>
5
4
False
>>
```

Look at these FileSystemObject methods:

```
>> sFSpec = "C:\Some\Where\whaterver.xlsx"
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetParentFolderName(sFSpec)
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetBaseName(sFSpec)
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetExtensionName(sFSpec)
>>
C:\Some\Where
whaterver
xlsx
>>
```

Comment: I see what you mean.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.